# Null coalescing operator with the variable itself

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, null-coalescing-operator

Is there any way of reduce the null coalescing operator expression when the variable we check is the one we will assign if it's not null?

Example:

```
DateTime? date1 = DateTime.Parse("11/05/1990");
DateTime? date2 = DateTime.Now;
date1 = date1 ?? date2;
```

For instance, something like that:

```
date1 = ?? date2;
```

I know that's not a big deal but I'm curious.

Comment: You cant. Check out list of operators at msdn if you are interested https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: Yes I tried and I got an "Expression excepted" error.

Comment: There have been requests for a `??=` operator or something similar. but it doesn't exist. It's not important enough for them to take the time and effort to implement it.

Comment: I would prefer null checking with if statement to prevent extra assignment. `if(date == null) date = date2;`. This is also not micro optimization, its just matter of opinion

Comment: I don't know why you chose this example and maybe your real code would benefit by such an operator, but I just wanted to make sure, that you know why this example is misleading: Both `date1` and `date2` are `Nullable`s, but will and can never be `null`.

Comment: @lukegv : Yes it was a quick example extracted but modified from my code. In my code, both variables can be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this does not exist in C#.

You can find the list of operators in https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/6a71f45d.aspx.

But isn't `date1 = date1 ?? date2` short enough already ?

Comment: Thank you for this simple and complete question.
Yes it is but like I said, I'm curious and that question was always in my mind when I was in that case. Now, I will now.

Answer (score 2):

No. If there was then:

```
_field ?? (_field = CalculateFieldValue());
```

wouldn't be so common in memoised properties.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), the null-coalescing assignment operator, `??=`, is available.

So it would be

```
date1 ??= date2;
```